# SQL - Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery, inner-join

I want to update a field, if the results are true

```
if(SELECT * FROM table1 AS A INNER JOIN table2 AS B
ON A.field1=B.field1
INNER JOIN table3 AS C
 ON  C.field1=B.field1) > 0
    UPDATE table3 SET table3.field2=(SELECT A.field3 FROM table1 AS A INNER JOIN table2 AS B
    ON A.field1=B.field1
    INNER JOIN table3 AS C
    ON C.field1=B.field1)
```

Comment: What is the question here? Please provide table structure, sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if(SELECT * FROM table1 AS A INNER JOIN table2 AS B
ON A.field1=B.field1
INNER JOIN table3 AS C
 ON  C.field1=B.field1) > 0
```

Supposing your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 AS A 
    INNER JOIN table2 AS B
        ON A.field1=B.field1
    INNER JOIN table3 AS C
        ON  C.field1=B.field1
```

Returns 500 rows, how do you expect to compare this to `0`? I suspect you want to use `IF EXISTS`:

```
IF EXISTS 
(   SELECT * 
    FROM table1 AS A 
        INNER JOIN table2 AS B
            ON A.field1=B.field1
        INNER JOIN table3 AS C
            ON  C.field1=B.field1
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE table3 
    SET table3.field2 = (   SELECT A.field3 
                            FROM table1 AS A 
                                INNER JOIN table2 AS B
                                    ON A.field1=B.field1
                                INNER JOIN table3 AS C
                                    ON C.field1=B.field1
                        );
END
```

However, this query looks wrong to me, it will through an error if more than one record exists, and there is no correlation between the inner and outer query, I suspect you actually want something like:

```
UPDATE c
SET Field2 = A.Field3
FROM table1 AS A 
    INNER JOIN table2 AS B
        ON A.field1=B.field1
    INNER JOIN table3 AS C
        ON C.field1=B.fieldl;
```

But, the exists check in itself is redundant, if nothing exists then the update will just do nothing, unless you are doing something different in the `ELSE` branch, you may as well just run the update without checking if it will affect any rows first.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 AS A INNER JOIN table2 AS B
ON A.field1=B.field1
INNER JOIN table3 AS C
 ON  C.field1=B.field1) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE table3 SET table3.field2=(SELECT A.field3 FROM table1 AS A INNER JOIN table2 AS B
    ON A.field1=B.field1
    INNER JOIN table3 AS C
    ON C.field1=B.field1)
END;
```